# Vis.js: Can you show properties on hovering?

Tags: properties, hover, nodes, vis.js, edges

I know that hovering on a node can show the title property. But can I also show other properties? Also, how about doing the same for edges?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the title property on edges as well.
and you will need to generate the title attribute before binding it to the network.

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, label: "Node 1", title: 'generate text before binding the sets' },
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 1, to: 3, title: 'from 1 to 3' },
  { from: 1, to: 2, title: 'from one 2 two' },
  { from: 2, to: 4 },
  { from: 2, to: 5 },
  { from: 3, to: 3 }
]);
```

see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/TERMIN/g9mxba61/)